# Should I repay my Home Buyer's Plan (HBP) RRSP loan early, or over the allowed 15 years?

Tags: canada, taxes, rrsp

I used my RRSP to purchase my house. It was tax free because I was first a time home buyer.

I am wondering if it would be beneficial to put the lump sum back in ASAP or take the 15 years to pay it back as I am allowed.

Will I benefit at tax time like I did before I took it out? Do I have to do anything special?

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no advantage.  There may be some peace of mind at no cost if you are already in the lowest tax bracket.  Otherwise, it is actually disadvantageous.

Consider the following scenario:
RRSP HBP withdrawal $15000 ($1000/y repayment),

You are required to pay back $1000 a year with no tax advantage.

Any additional RRSP payments can be designated as HBP (no tax advantage) or as a regular RRSP contribution **Tax = (Taxable Income - contributions) * rate.**

So, you are forgoing the tax benefit for no advantage.

Comment: I see, so does that mean I have to let someone (the person who does my taxes?) know what I intend my contributions to be used for (repayment or regular RRSP contribution)?

Comment: Yes.  There is a line somewhere in there in the RRSP that asks you to specify if there was a HBP repayment.

Comment: Heh, I had not been assuming that you would either repay your HBP RRSP or keep the money entirely outside of your RRSP. If you have $15,000 now _AND_ expect to raise 15,000 over the next ten years, your best bet would indeed be to invest $15,000 in RRSPs now and pay back the HBP over the next ten years. Personally, I'd rather clear the debt off now, but I'm fiscally conservative.

Comment: It's not really a debt.  It's your money, the government is simply allowing you to withdraw from your RRSP without a tax penalty, provided you pay it off over 15 years.  If you had 15,000 AND could reasonably assume that you will have 1000 per year to make the payments, you are actually forgoing the tax advantage on the additional 14,000.  If you're in a high bracket, only pay the minimum.  If you're in a low bracket and anticipate being in a higher bracket in the near future, then pay it off and contribute the $1000 per year in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You will not benefit at tax time like you did with your initial contributions, because you have already benefited and are simply repaying your withdrawn contributions. However, capital gains are not taxed inside of your RRSP, until you withdraw the money.

Let's say you have $10,000 to repay and have all the money now. It makes sense to repay it immediately. Whatever interest or capital gains you make inside of the RRSP are not taxed. However, your $10,000 contribution this year will not offer you any deductions on your tax return.

There are exactly two reasons I can see to not immediately repay the full amount, if able. First, you may need the money for an emergency fund, and there are significant implications for removing money from your RRSP in such a case. Second, if you believe you will be in a higher tax bracket when you retire, it may not make sense to put any money into an RRSP right now.

Almost certainly, you want to repay the entire lump sum if able.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Your second reason for not paying it back right away, being in a higher tax bracket at retirement... What affect would this have? I hope I will earn more money in the future as my career is still young.

Comment: Most people, when they retire, pull out something below 100% of their pre-retirement income each month, from their RRSPs. There are two benefits to RRSPs. First, you get to defer paying taxes until retirement (thus compounding the money saved until then). Second, most likely you'll pay less tax. Living the high life, you may make $100,000 at retirement, but pull only $75,000 a year from your RRSPs. Assuming you are more than ten years from retirement, the benefit from compounding interest on your deferred taxes is the far bigger benefit for you.

Comment: If you expect to win the lottery, you would expect your income (from investments) to be significantly HIGHER during your retirement. But then, do you really care about having to pay a bit more tax? In almost all other cases, the RRSP tax benefits work out in your favour.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like I should pay it back as soon as I can. Does the government automatically know that I am paying it back, or do I have to notify them? I have been paying back bits here and there, and still giving in my slips to claim at tax time.

Comment: You notify the government on your next tax return. As far as the banks are concerned, you are just putting your money into an RRSP.

Answer (score 2):

If you have (other) high interest debt, say over 8%, pay it back first. Else, you are likely best off paying this loan back and getting the money working for you long term.

Answer (score 0):

Paying this off early is robbing yourself of the extra earning potential for this money.  Think of it as an interest free loan from your future self.  If you can otherwise use that money to get a better rate of return then you are better off putting it there.  Best options would normally be to use it to buy additional regular RRSPs, RESPs, or TFSA because of government benefits but even puting the extra into a GIC for a year is better than paying back home buyers plan early.